# TortoiseGit Diff not showing up in context menu

Tags: windows-10, tortoisegit

Scenario:

I have Windows 7 with TortoiseGit 2.2.0 on my machine. 
Added a Git user recently, she got 2.4.0 installed on her Windows 10 machine.

The issue is with the right-click context menu on her machine. The options "Diff" and "Diff with previous version" are not showing up in the Windows context menu or the "extended" TortoiseGit menu on her machine. Other items, like Push/Pull/Fetch show up fine in the extended menu.

These items were all checked in the "Set Extend Menu Item" options in TortoiseGit. I tried adding them to the "Context Menu" settings as well, tried restarting her machine after. This did not work, either. The Diff options just are not showing up in her menus. We've tried right-clicking both files and folders in the git repositories. They just never show up.

What might not be set right?

Comment: Items selected for "Set extended menu" only show up if you hold the shift key when opening the context menu. please read the documentation!

Comment: That's weird. On my computer, it would add it to the TortoiseGit submenu when I checked it. Shift does make it appear on hers. However, adding to the normal "Context Menu" does nothing... how do I get it to appear without holding shift?

Answer (score 1):

Checking for "Extended context menu" the item is only shown when you hold the SHIFT key when opening the context menu - this is also stated above the list. To move it to the TortoiseGit submenu, uncheck it on the "Context menu" settings page.

Please see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-look-feel.